# Read web.config settings in html page without extension

Tags: html, web-config

I need to read web.config settings. I have added following settings to web.config

```
<handlers>
<remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />      
   <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-HTML" path="*.html"
                verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"
                resourceType="Unspecified"  preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"  />
```

and

```
<buildProviders>
<add extension=".html"
             type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />        
</buildProviders>
```

It works fine for all html pages that have.html in extension.
But for pages urls like [http://testsite.com/aaa](http://testsite.com/sss) which displays 404 html page in response , the configuration is not read.

What can be done to include pages without extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue for error pages.
After changing settings for httpErrors in web.config, things worked for me.

I changed

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="holdingClientError.html" responseMode="File"  />
```

To

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/holdingClientError.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
```